# How to store all the table data in variable in php

Tags: php, mysqli

My php code is

```
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM album");
if($result)
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $data['path'] = $row['photo_path'];
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

I want to store the all photos path in `$data['path']`
What Happening is it taking only last inserted value. I am not getting how can I store the all paths and then echo it.

Comment: make it an array

Comment: I also used that but in jquery it just console Array and give an error. If you can guide me how it can be used as array then it will be great

Comment: @MohammedSabir check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add array otherwise it will overwrite values

```
 $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM album");
if($result)
{
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $data[]['path'] = $row['photo_path'];
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also overwrite previous data. So, you are getting last value.

```
 $data['path'] = $row['photo_path'];
```

Use, array instead something like

```
 $data[$i]['path'] = $row['photo_path'];
 $i++;
```

Comment: not sure, why do people do downvote and doesn't post their comment. At least, tell what needs to be corrected

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the path you can do:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT photo_path as path FROM album");
if($result)
{ 
    $data = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data);         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to turn the result into an array:

```
$array = iterator_to_array($result);
```

The `$array` is an array that contains all result rows (again as array, array inside array).

More verbose example:

```
$result = $link->query("SELECT photo_path as path FROM album");
if ($result) {
    $data = iterator_to_array($result);
} else {
    $data = ['error' => $link->error];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```